# Can't use mysqld with empty password from command line

Tags: mysql

First, I create a database directory:

```
$ mysql_install_db --datadir=./foo
```

Then, I start mysql daemon:

```
$ mysqld --port=5555 --datadir=./foo &
```

It starts fine and I can connect to it using, for example, Navicat. I'm trying to connect from shell:

```
$ mysql --user=root --port=5555 --password=
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What to do? I also tried to change password first for root user:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -P 5555 password foo
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Again, connection works perfectly fine from a standalone SQL application, like Navicat.

Comment: have you tried `--password=''`?

Comment: yes, tried it - the same result

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I am aware of to log in to an account with an empty or blank password. The first is to just omit the password option.

```
$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 163714
Server version: 5.6.38 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Another way is to specify the `-p` option, and just hit the enter key when prompted.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 163719
Server version: 5.6.38 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the user accounts include the host you are connecting from.  Hence, `root@localhost` and `root@192.168.0.1` are different users and can have different passwords.  Either of them can also not even exist.

Try this query and check whether your root users have different passwords.

```
SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';
```

If they do, log in using whatever method works and change the password of the `root@localhost` user to what you want it to be.  (An empty string will be no password, however no password, especially for privileged users, is generally considered to be a bad idea.)

Comment: I have to use empty password, it's an integration test scenario (difficult to explain the big picture). The problem is that I can't login with an empty password - yes, the user is there for the 'localhost' domain.

Comment: It's *there* but does it have a password and is the password different from the other root user?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick:

```
$ mysqld --port=5555 --datadir=./foo --socket=./sock &
```

And then later:

```
$ mysql --socket=./sock --user=root --port=5555
```

Works fine.